# Facebook OG Meta Tags in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-opengraph

In my rails application, I want to connect the FB OG Meta Tags dynamically with the page that the user is currently on. I feel like this should be straightforward, but can't get it to work properly.

For example, I have "Idea" Pages, on which there is an Idea title and an Idea Description.

Currently, in my Application.html.erb file I have this (and am getting a NoMethodError for title):

```
<meta property="og:title" content= <%= "#{@idea.title.titleize}" %>/>
<meta property="og:url" content= <%= "http://myurl.com/ideas/#{@idea.id}" %>/>
<meta property="og:description" content= <%= "#{@idea.short_description}" %>/>
```

Is there an issue with my syntax? With the availability of these instance variables? I'm not sure I totally understand how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Yes as noob mentioned, make the content declaration be within quotes.

```
<meta property="og:description" content= "<%= @idea.short_description %>" />
```

To make these meta tags dynamic in Rails, people first started using the pretty page title method described by Ryan Bates in the [pretty page title railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title)

However, I just came across **this meta-tags gem which looks extremely promising**: [meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags)

With the gem, manage any meta tag, make them dynamic and SEO friendly.  Example:

```
set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login'
# <title>Some Page Title</title>
```

Easily set all facebook:og tags at once:

```
  set_meta_tags :og => {
                  :title    => 'The Rock',
                  :type     => 'video.movie',
                  :url      => 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/',
                  :image    => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg',
                  :video    => {
                    :director => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000881/',
                    :writer   => ['http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0918711/', 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0177018/']
                  }
                }
```

The above code outputs the following html when you then call `<%=display_meta_tags%>`:

`<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:video:director" content="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000881/"/>
<meta property="og:video:writer" content="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0918711/"/>
<meta property="og:video:writer" content="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0177018/"/>`

Many more examples in the source code and github repo.  The last tag set takes precedence, so if you set one in your layout, then another in your page, seems like the one in the page will take precedence.

If you use this, just make sure you have `<%= display_meta_tags %>` in your layout page i.e. `application.html.erb`.

Comment: Hey Danny, is the Gem compatible with Rails 4 ?

Comment: It appears to be (i haven't had any issues and have upgraded to rails 4), however I don't see any recent commits mentioning anything to do with rails 4 and it's not listed on http://ready4rails4.net/.

Comment: that gem is a winner... whoa.  took me a few minutes to find... call `set_meta_tags` from your controllers, and pair it with `<%= display_meta_tags %>` in the head of `layouts/application`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
<meta property="og:description" content= "<%= @idea.short_description %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This link is also worth checking - 
http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/07/12/rails-concerns-iii-metatags/

I have taken the above link help but that doesn't worked. The OG meta tags are not working.

Lets see what helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please read my blog post for a detailed explanation of a straightforward way to get this working in a rails application as a whole--perhaps you could extrapolate for adding it to specific pages.  I'm not sure it will address your specific concerns but might have some useful information for debugging. http://blog.gingergriffis.com/post/59812374302/rails-app-thumbnail-on-facebook

The main point of my blog post that might be useful is the facebook debugger tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

And here are the settings I used in my application.html.erb file:

```
<meta property=”og:title” content=”Ginger Griffis” /> 
<meta property=”og:type” content=”website” /> 
<meta property=”og:url” content=”http://www.gingergriffis.com/” /> 
<meta property=”og:image” content=”http://www.gingergriffis.com/assets/mylogolarge.jpg” /> 
<meta property=”og:description” content=”I am a RoR web dev...” />
```

Comment: Thanks kleopatra--I'm fairly new to this and appreciate the feedback.  The main point of my blog post that might be useful is the facebook debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. And here are the settings I used in my application.html.erb file: `<meta property=”og:title” content=”Ginger Griffis” />

<meta property=”og:type” content=”website” />

<meta property=”og:url” content=”http://www.gingergriffis.com/” />

<meta property=”og:image” content=”http://www.gingergriffis.com/assets/mylogolarge.jpg” />

<meta property=”og:description” content=”I am a RoR web dev...” />`

Comment: being new is no problem, hope my reminder is gentle enough :-) BTW, you can edit your answer and add the details (in your comment) there, it'll be much more readable.